# Integrated terminal VSCode: Showing paths but not output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I run files in VS Code, I get quote a bit of gobbledegook and not the output I'm expecting.

Like so:

[image]

I've changed launch.json like so:

```
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "internalConsole", 
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

What's going on here?

The good news is that the DEBUG CONSOLE returns the output I'm expecting. But shouldn't that output be in the terminal as well?

(On a related note, what's a good way to learn basic terminal commands?)

Comment: I always expect to see the number `42` but that never happens. What do you expect to see? Have you tried to set a breakpoint? If you see the output you expect what's the deal where it is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, here are the following suggestions:

1. "Terminal information". The information displayed by the terminal is useful. It shows us the path information of the script that needs to be run, as well as the current VSCode running environment information and so on.
2. "Showing paths but not output".  When you debug the script, you don’t see the running result in the terminal because you set the debug output mode: `"console": "internalConsole",`. It makes the debugging results displayed in the internal debugging console instead of the terminal.

   The default is:`"console": "integratedTerminal"`,The result is displayed in the terminal in VSCode. If you set it to: `"console": "externalTerminal",`The result will open a new cmd window, and only display the running result:

   [image]

   For setting the display to the terminal, please refer to: [Set configuration options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options).
3. For more terminal information, you could refer to: [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).